# want to display array output in a same row in php

Tags: php, arrays

This is what I have achieved so far.

```
$product1 = array("Watch"=>"100$", "Shoes"=>"550$", "Jacket"=>"430$" , "Sweater"=>"230$" );
$product2 = array("Watch"=>"200$", "Shoes"=>"450$", "Jacket"=>"430$" , "Sweater"=>"230$" );
$product3 = array("Watch"=>"300$", "Shoes"=>"350$", "Jacket"=>"430$" , "Sweater"=>"230$" );
$product4 = array("Watch"=>"400$", "Shoes"=>"250$", "Jacket"=>"430$" , "Sweater"=>"230$" );

foreach($product1 as $x => $x_value) {
    echo "Name=" . $x ."<br>". ", Price=" . $x_value."<br>";
}

foreach($product2 as $x => $x_value) {
    echo "Name=" . $x ."<br>". ", Price=" . $x_value."<br>";
}
```

I want the product1 output in 1st row and in first four columns.
Similary product2 output in 2nd row and in four columns.

Desired result:
[image: expected output]

Comment: Please start reading a few "getting started" tutorials about HTML page layout. There is little sense in us repeating all that here if you can simply read it elsewhere on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like that:

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';


foreach ($product1 as $x => $x_value) {
    echo '<td>';
    echo "Name=" . $x ."<br>". "Price=" . $x_value;
    echo '</td>';
}


echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';


foreach ($product2 as $x => $x_value) {
    echo '<td>';
    echo "Name=" . $x ."<br>". "Price=" . $x_value;
    echo '</td>';
}


echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';


foreach ($product3 as $x => $x_value) {
    echo '<td>';
    echo "Name=" . $x ."<br>". "Price=" . $x_value;
    echo '</td>';
}


echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';


foreach ($product4 as $x => $x_value) {
    echo '<td>';
    echo "Name=" . $x ."<br>". "Price=" . $x_value;
    echo '</td>';
}


echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

[Demo](https://www.tehplayground.com/MWfHvWdH1IRmnsdF)